# ¿Cuál es la forma más efeciente de reemplazar una palabra por otra en un archivo muy muy grande utilizando python?

Tags: python

Quiero reemplazar las palabras en ingles por sus traduciones en español en un texto muy muy extenso, cual seria la forma mas eficiente de hacer esto utlizando python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esta sería la forma mas optima, **evitando usar `read()` o `readlines()`** :

```
with open("datos.txt") as miArchivo:
    for line in miArchivo:
         traducir(line)
```

Tu texto al ser traducido debería ser guardado a un archivo evitando almacenarlo en la memoria.